# thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' has overflowed its stack fatal runtime error: stack overflow Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: runtime, evm, grandpa, poa

we are running a stand alone Blockchain network by using POA consensus mechanism. The chain was working fine and after producing 8 Lac Blocks the nodes we down and now i have tried to re-execute same command, i'm getting this error.

**What Could be Reasons of this ? and what can be the solution.**

2023-10-18 06:45:57  The bootnode you want to connect to at `/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWBFHeTFUUVQTVWxx7WaFueHMpzEzYjjSkLy5NhV6sQFNE` provided a different peer ID `12D3KooWSPRkv3Ji89TDjcWCcxqkhJTEWyp9FHCjnShRo3jcGvwR` than the one you expect `12D3KooWBFHeTFUUVQTVWxx7WaFueHMpzEzYjjSkLy5NhV6sQFNE`.
2023-10-18 06:45:57  The bootnode you want to connect to at `/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWBFHeTFUUVQTVWxx7WaFueHMpzEzYjjSkLy5NhV6sQFNE` provided a different peer ID `12D3KooWSPRkv3Ji89TDjcWCcxqkhJTEWyp9FHCjnShRo3jcGvwR` than the one you expect `12D3KooWBFHeTFUUVQTVWxx7WaFueHMpzEzYjjSkLy5NhV6sQFNE`.
2023-10-18 06:45:59 Detected prevote equivocation in the finality worker: Equivocation { round_number: 8, identity: Public(d17c2d7823ebf260fd138f2d7e27d114c0145d968b5ff5006125f2414fadae69 (5GoNkf6W...)), first: (Prevote { target_hash: 0xaedeecc53bc2152cb5382d14e9931258a8490bfd9b18da1f69c7537f84259f94, target_number: 830370 }, Signature(38ebcd6981c20436628e4e068e20f9f6e2cc6fb9726615fb9cda66cc691f1603fa7483aa5d9ea7395b4f117f6422edb0d50e6adc2b7e244d2d2a46d097bc7504)), second: (Prevote { target_hash: 0x23ae4b3367cf78c298b59814fe4f6016a76a330c479dca0509a8289cc10aeb71, target_number: 830361 }, Signature(25392566364fb2264076e1c473c7b772c5fc0e3d8bb1f7649ee1af0acc0bd9f41282593d677197c13df93e124cd419158ad43c33ae85c083f8f8f1f9779d7405)) }
2023-10-18 06:45:59 Error reporting prevote equivocation: safety invariant has been violated: Refraining from sending equivocation report for our own equivocation.

```
**thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
Aborted (core dumped)**
```

Comment: Can you send us your GitHub code link?

Answer (score 0):

I purged the chain and restarted, it worked fine